# How to find principal integral of $y''''-y'''-3y''+5y'-2y = xe^x +3e^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> how to find the principal integral of $y''''-y'''-3y''+5y'-2y = xe^x +3e^{-2x}$ ?

I don't need its final answer; I just want to learn to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't need its final answer; I just want to learn to solve this.

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime \prime \prime \prime}-y^{\prime \prime \prime}-3 y^{\prime \prime}+5 y^{\prime}-2 y-x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}-3 \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}=0}
\end{gather*}
This is higher order nonhomogeneous ODE. Let the solution be
$$
     y = y_h + y_p 
    $$
Where $y_h$ is the solution to the homogeneous ODE
And $y_p$ is a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous ODE. $y_h$ is the solution to
$$
     y^{\prime \prime \prime \prime}-y^{\prime \prime \prime}-3 y^{\prime \prime}+5 y^{\prime}-2 y = 0
    $$
The characteristic equation is
$$
      \lambda^{4}-\lambda^{3}-3 \lambda^{2}+5 \lambda -2 = 0
   $$
The roots of the above equation are
\begin{align*}
   \lambda_1 &= -2\\ 
               \lambda_2 &= 1\\ 
               \lambda_3 &= 1\\ 
               \lambda_4 &= 1
               \end{align*}
Therefore the homogeneous solution is
$$
      y_h(x)={\mathrm e}^{-2 x} c_{1}+{\mathrm e}^{x} c_{2}+x \,{\mathrm e}^{x} c_{3}+x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x} c_{4}
$$
The fundamental set of solutions for the homogeneous solution are the following
\begin{align*}
y_1 &= {\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\\
y_2 &= {\mathrm e}^{x}\\
y_3 &= x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}\\
y_4 &= x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x} 
\end{align*}
Now the particular solution to the given ODE is found
\begin{align*}
   y^{\prime \prime \prime \prime}-y^{\prime \prime \prime}-3 y^{\prime \prime}+5 y^{\prime}-2 y = x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}+3 \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}
\end{align*}
The particular solution is found using the method of undetermined coefficients.
Looking at the RHS of the ode, which is
$$
   x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}+3 \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}
   $$
Shows that the corresponding undetermined set of the basis functions (UC_set) for the trial solution is
$$
    [\{{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}, \{x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}, {\mathrm e}^{x}\}]
   $$
While the set of the basis functions for the homogeneous solution found earlier is
$$
    \{x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}, x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}, {\mathrm e}^{x}, {\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}
   $$
Since ${\mathrm e}^{-2 x}$ is duplicated in the UC_set, then
this basis is multiplied by extra $x$. The UC_set becomes
$$
                    [\{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}, \{x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}, {\mathrm e}^{x}\}]
                    $$
Since ${\mathrm e}^{x}$ is duplicated in the UC_set, then
this basis is multiplied by extra $x$. The UC_set becomes
$$
                    [\{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}, \{x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}, x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}\}]
                    $$
Since $x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}$ is duplicated in the UC_set, then
this basis is multiplied by extra $x$. The UC_set becomes
$$
                    [\{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}, \{x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}, x^{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}\}]
                    $$
Since $x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}$ is duplicated in the UC_set, then
this basis is multiplied by extra $x$. The UC_set becomes
$$
                    [\{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}\}, \{x^{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}, x^{4} {\mathrm e}^{x}\}]
                    $$
the trial solution is a linear combination of all the basis function in
the above updated UC_set.
$$
   y_p = A_{1} x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}+A_{2} x^{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}+A_{3} x^{4} {\mathrm e}^{x}
    $$
The unknowns $\{A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}\}$ are found
by substituting the above trial solution $y_p$ into the ODE and comparing coefficients.
Substituting the trial solution into the ODE and simplifying gives
$$
       -x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}+18 A_{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}+24 A_{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}-27 A_{1} {\mathrm e}^{-2 x}+72 A_{3} x \,{\mathrm e}^{x}-3 \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x} = 0
       $$
Solving for the unknowns by comparing coefficients results in
$$
             \left[A_{1} = -{\frac{1}{9}}, A_{2} = -{\frac{1}{54}}, A_{3} = {\frac{1}{72}}\right]
             $$
Substituting the above back in the above trial solution $y_p$, gives the particular solution
$$
             y_p = -\frac{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}}{9}-\frac{x^{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}}{54}+\frac{x^{4} {\mathrm e}^{x}}{72}
             $$
Therefore the general solution is
\begin{align*} 
           y &= y_h + y_p\\
              &= \left({\mathrm e}^{-2 x} c_{1}+{\mathrm e}^{x} c_{2}+x \,{\mathrm e}^{x} c_{3}+x^{2} {\mathrm e}^{x} c_{4}\right) + \left(-\frac{x \,{\mathrm e}^{-2 x}}{9}-\frac{x^{3} {\mathrm e}^{x}}{54}+\frac{x^{4} {\mathrm e}^{x}}{72}\right)
\end{align*}